# Site provisioning wizard?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, site-collection, site-creation

I am using SP 2013 on prem, and need to create custom wizard for creating site collections.

I can use old school method of using an application page with c# etc, but I am instead looking for "the new way" to achieve this. Maybe use powershell, etc.

I guess there must be many guides around for this. If you got any tips of links for me, please post it here.

Comment: depends what the wizard does, what do you want the parameters to be? You could use powershell, but powershell does not have a GUI, so it wouldn't be your typical wizard.

Comment: Hi Mike, I think a list should do: i.e. as described by Waqas Sarwar MCSE in the post below.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this way( i am guessing you are developer).

- Create a List in SharePoint with all required column( Site collection name, url, Owners, Site template etc)as per your requirement.One special field which will indicate whether this request processed or not( true/false type).
- Now create PowerShell Script, which will read from List and create the site collection for each un-processed row.
- Now you can schedule you Powershell in a Task Schedule which will run as per your requirement( every hour/day etc).
- Or you can Replace the power-shell task schedule with a custom timer job.

Comment: +1 for guessing correctly ;). Yes, this is the kind of thing I am looking for. I once saw some code for this approach by an MVP, but cannot find it again. Maybe you got some intel on that?

Comment: If you go this approach, I'd recommend using powershell over a timer job anyday.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you need to create a wizard with the user interaction, powershell is not the alternative.

It is correct to use an application page. With C # code.

Another alternative is that the sites are created in a list and trigger an event receiver with c# code to create the site collection.

By using SSOM you have many tools for flexible solutions.

Of course all this is debatable. If I had to, I would opt for this option. Any queries do not stop asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create an app to facilitate this. You can make it SharePoint-hosted, and it would just have a form that a user fills out to execute a creating on a SharePoint site collection. This may be a little harder than a SharePoint list + powershell, but the app makes it easy to port over from site to site.

- Create an app using the App Model in Visual Studios
- Create the form in your app that allows users to fill out required fields
- Upon a submit button the app model uses CSOM to reach out and create the site collection and sends an email with the link of the new site collection to the user when it's completed.

Here's an article about how to create site collections using CSOM: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2014/06/09/provisioning-site-collections-using-sp-app-model-in-on-premises-with-just-csom/